# How to check if its an invalid user

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

```
//Check Validity of User   
var searchedUser =  document.getElementById("User_Field").value;

var Userref = firebase.database().ref("User/" + searchedUser);
Userref .on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var CheckUser = snapshot.val();
    if (CheckUser != searchedUser)
        alert ("Invalid User");
});
```

I wanted to check if the entered User from my html is registered, the if statement works but even when user is valid, it still alert that its an invalid user. Please help or advice. Thank you

Comment: debugging 101 ... `console.log(CheckUser)` is it the same as `console.log(searchedUser);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of CheckUser using console.log(CheckUser), same with searchedUser. using the information you gathered using console.log, use that as the operation inside your if statement

Answer (score 0):

Two things to be checked here

- How many times `on` method is called ? If its called multiple times then at some time value is different. Print `console.log` on every invocation and check.
- The attributes `CheckUser` and `searchedUser` are actually different at one of the instants.